# Can't get/access elements until inspecting in browser (Old/legacy ASPX)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, legacy

A lot of the webiste has been migrated and is now contained/built in ASP.NET Framework v4.6.X, but there are still some legacy parts that are built in ASPX v3.X, so think about these old projects are rendered in a sub-frame (main screen frame is ASP.NET v4.6 and some ASPX V3.X solutions are redered in a sub-square of the screen).
The problem is basically that in this legacy ASPX project/solution elements can't be accessed from web browser's console until I inspect any part of the sub-framed rendered document.
So when the page loads initially elements can't be accessed, if I inspect any part of the main frame (ASP.NET v4.6.X) elements still won't be available, only if I inspect any element of the sub-framed part (which renders from ASPX 3.X ) then the elements will be accessible.

The following is an example of how the behavior, tested in Firefox, Edge and Chrome

```
// initial page load
document.forms
--> HTMLCollection { length: 0 }

// after inspected any part of main frame
document.forms
--> HTMLCollection { length: 0 }

// after inspected any part of the aspx sub-frame
--> HTMLCollection { 0: form#Form1, length: 1, … }
```

Also I have tried added the following tags in Web.config file (neither of them worked):

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
...
</pages>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not at all sure what you mean by "sub-frame". Are you using iframes are not? That is the only issue I can suggest that will EVER matter here. Using .net 4.8, .net 3.5, or even .net core? Then that matters ZERO here, but I repeat ZERO here. How the web server renders HTML does not matter and the client side browser developer tools do not care, or even know how that HTML was created, only that it was! As I stated, the ONLY issue that may well matter is if you using iframes here.  So, using .net 4.0, or 2.0, or 3.5 or version xx? Does not matter